# How to make 1920-1080px html page fit screen and remove whitespace

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website which is 1920-1080px but It doesn't fit the screen as it is too big. I have removed the margin and padding and it works but it is too big to fit the screen. there is white space on the right side of the page with no scrollbar. If I scale it to fit, It has a scroll bar and so it does not fit the screen

```
#Home_Page {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    --web-view-name: Home Page;
    --web-view-id: Home_Page;
    --web-scale-to-fit: true;
    --web-scale-on-resize: true;
    --web-refresh-for-changes: true;
    --web-enable-deep-linking: true;
}
```

I expected it to be full screen and scrollable.

Comment: I might still not understand everything here, but I think your problem comes from the fact that all of your divs are `position: absolute` with fix coordinates, widths and heights. It means that all the elements of your page will stay the same size, even if you resize the browser window. Hence, you can't have a dynamic layout, so you'll always have a white space on the right side of your webpage if your browser window is not exactly the size of your content. That's a huge work you've done here, but there simpler ways for a better outcome. You might want to check out CSS Grid for that.

Comment: Please show at least a skeletal markup layout. It's difficult to work with one bit of CSS and nothing else.

Comment: so what should I do? get rid of the fixed coordinates in the homepage?                      Here is the code : https://pastebin.com/abL1ch9S                                                     It's too big to fit in the actual question

Comment: What are those properties prefixed with `--web-`, and are they relevant here?

Comment: You should be able to create a simplified demo. Four boxes and a wrapper would be enough, no?

Comment: I can't seem to edit it . It says you can only edit after 5minutes but still after 5 minutes, I can't. And the website requires everything to be seen. just some boxes and a wrapper aren't enough. So please, If you have an answer, Post it as this is urgent

Comment: Try this in your body tag `margin:0;  padding:0;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem here, but if you want your "Home_Page" div to be full screen, you should consider the vh and vw units, such as:

```
#Home_Page{
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 …
```

100vw being 100% of your viewport width, it dynamically adapt to the width of the browser's viewport width.

If you want to keep a minimal width of 1366px, then:

```
#Home_Page{
 width: 100vw;
 min-width: 1366px;
 height: 100vh;
 …
```

Comment: I have a scrollbar vertically on this one and it still dosen't fit. here is the full code:                  https://pastebin.com/abL1ch9S

Comment: Okay. I'm tried to resize an element and it worked. Now i'll confirm if 1920-1080 works. thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can't fit a web page with static sizes everywhere becuase different users have different monitors/displays. Even if you achieved it in some way, the image would probably be a bit blury after upscaling it.

As DimNC pointed out earlier, you should consider creating a responsive page or set your element's `height` to `100vh` and `width` to `100vw`.
vh comes from vierport height and
vw from viewport width.

That way your page will "adapt" to various screen and browser sizes dynamically.

```
#Home_Page {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
}
```